# php else statement not working (closed)

Tags: php, if-statement

I have code like this

```
function change_lang($lang,$page,$city) {

    $chglang = [];

    if($page == 'Province' || 'Provinsi') {

        if($lang == 'en') {
            $query = $this->db->query ("SELECT slugId AS slug FROM `navbar` WHERE slugEn='$city'"); 
        }
        else {
            $query = $this->db->query ("SELECT slugEn AS slug FROM `navbar` WHERE slugId='$city'");
        }

        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
            $chglang[] = ['chglang' => $row['slug'] ];
        }

    }

    else {

        if($lang == 'en') {
            $query = $this->db->query ("SELECT slugId AS slug FROM `navbar` WHERE slugEn='$page'"); 
        }
        else {
            $query = $this->db->query ("SELECT slugEn AS slug FROM `navbar` WHERE slugId='$page'");
        }

        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
            $chglang[] = ['chglang' => $row['slug'] ];
        }

    }

    return $chglang;

}
```

the `$chglang[]` only filled if the `$page = Province` or `$page = Provinsi`. So if the `$page` has different value than `Province` or `Provinsi` the `$chglang[]` array will be an empty array. It means the else condition is not working. Am I miss something in code?

Comment: `$page == 'Province' || 'Provinsi'` This condition, doesn't do what you think it does :) Your condition will be evaluated as followed: `(($page == 'Province') || 'Provinsi')`

Comment: `if($page == 'Province' || $page == 'Provinsi') {`

Comment: It's working with `if($page == 'Province' || $page == 'Provinsi')`. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your else is never invoked is becuase your if clause is always true.

```
if($page == 'Province' || 'Provinsi')
```

The reason this always evaluates to true is because 'Provinsi' by itself is a value that does not evaluate to 0, NULL, or false. If it doesn't evaluate to 0, NULL, or false, it is considered to be TRUE. Therefore what you wrote is basically saying the same thing as:

```
if($page == 'Province' || TRUE)
```

So, if even if the first condition evaluates to be FALSE, the second one will always be TRUE, and your if clause will be TRUE.

To fix this, you need to use:

```
if($page == 'Province' || $page == 'Provinsi')
```

Answer (score 0):

if($page == 'Province' || 'Provinsi')

Is wrong, change it to

```
if($page == 'Province' || $page == 'Provinsi') {
```

Comment: It's technical not wrong, it just doesn't do what OP probably wants it to do

Comment: Yes indeed... Evaluating a const char as boolean is not what he intended